# Rowspan not using top row

Tags: html, css, html-table, row

I don't understand why my column won't span to the top and bottom rows I created. It is supposed to look like the "Today" column is taller on the top and bottom then the other columns.

It's a lot of code, and I wasn't sure what I should cut without deforming it all or adding a new variable (it needs a fluid height).
JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/DaAwesomeP/aU9Le/

Basic HTML Layout:

```
<table id="weatherForecast">
  <tr class="weatherForecast-row-outer">
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="weatherForecast-row">
    <td id="weatherForecast-DATE" class="weatherForecast-day  weatherForecast-day-today" rowspan="3">
    <!-- Cell Content for "Today" Here -->
      <td id="weatherForecast-DATE" class="weatherForecast-day ">
      <!-- Cell Content Here -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="weatherForecast-row-outer">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Here is an image that shows what I want:

[image]

Comment: This question is apparently about an attempt to solve a design problem using `rowspan` and `colspan` in a manner that violates the HTML table model. The modified question, with links to a page and to an image, is still vague and subject to interpretations, and it asks for design help, so it’s off-topic here. Besides, the approach is probably wrong: the issue seems to be to show a table so that one cell is displaced, which is probably better handled with CSS positioning than an HTML table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got rid of the all of the  `rowspan` and just gave one cell `display: block`. I can then adjust the height of that cell specifically without changing the others. I used `calc` to provide a variable height.

Answer (score 0):

The table markup violates the HTML table model rules, as the W3C HTML [Validator](http://validator.w3.org) tells you if you use it in HTML5 mode.

Since there are two cells on the second row, the first row should occupy two columns, too, so set `colspan=2` on its `td` element.

And you cannot use `rowspan=3`, since there aren’t just enough rows in the table to span. Use `rowspan=2` instead.

It’s difficult to tell what you actually want (a drawing would have helped), but the following would at least be valid HTML (note that I fixed a problem with duplicate `id` values too):

```
<table id="weatherForecast" border>
  <tr class="weatherForecast-row-outer">
    <td colspan=2></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="weatherForecast-row">
    <td id="weatherForecast-DATE" class="weatherForecast-day weatherForecast-day-today" rowspan="2">
    <!-- Cell Content for "Today" Here -->
      <td id="weatherForecast-DATE2" class="weatherForecast-day ">
      <!-- Cell Content Here -->
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr class="weatherForecast-row-outer">
      <td></td>
    </tr>
```

Comment: I fixed the `rowspan`, but the `colspan` didn't do anything. You can see my full table in the fiddle (there are actually five columns).  I tried changing it to five as well. The bottom row is working correctly, but the top is not. I only want the first column to have the `rowspan`. I also added an image.